# Edit style of multiple objects in Xcode/Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, oop

I'm very new to iPhone development (and programming in general)

I am currently applying a shadow to an object 'settingsButton'. I want to ensure that the style applied to this object is also applied to a further 3 objects (mapButton, informationButton & reportButton').

What is the best method to do so? I'm currently using the following code for 'settingsButton'

```
self.settingsButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.settingsButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f,5.0f);
    self.settingsButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.settingsButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
    self.settingsButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the buttons are IBOutlet, you can create an IBOutletCollection, and link them into that collection.

For example;

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonArray;

@synthesize buttonArray;

- (void) editButtons
{
    for(UIButton* button in buttonArray)
        button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        ...
}
```

Or, if they are not IBOutlets, you can add them into an array.

For example;

```
@property NSMutableArray* buttonArray; // In .h

@synthesize buttonArray; // In .m

- (void) editButtons
{
    buttonArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    [buttonArray addObject:self.settingsButton];
    ...

    for(UIButton* button in buttonArray)
        button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        ...
}
```

If you're linking these buttons from an xib/storyboard, IBOutletCollection would be a better solution.